# Query mongodb using spark

Tags: mongodb, date, apache-spark

I am working on extracting large amount of data from mongo using apache spark.

My mongo Data is like

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56a3287a45ce7cc14e2c4a84"), "Product" : "Id","CreatedOn" : ISODate("2016-01-23T01:47:50Z")}
```

My spark query is

```
config.set("mongo.input.query","{CreatedOn: {'$gt': new  Date(1455561000000)}}).sort({_id:-1}");
```

which give me following exception

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{CreatedOn: {'$gt': new  Date(1455561000000)}}).sort({_id:-1}
```

same query

```
db.mycollection.find({CreatedOn: {'$gt': new  Date(1455561000000)}}).sort({_id:-1}"),
```

if I run on mongo shell, it runs fine.

I am using java to execute the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mongo.input.query` should be a valid JSON string and what you pass is clearly not a one. In a strict mode it should be something more or less like this (escape quotes where needed):

```
{"CreatedOn": {
    "$gt": {"$date": "2016-01-05T18:30:00Z"}
    "$lt": {"$date": "2016-01-22T18:30:00Z"}
}}
```

I doubt it is possible to pass ordering this way though especially since `$orderby` is deprecated.

Comment: Since I have huge data, I am looking for data to be selected withing particular datetime range in spark from mongo.e.g  data between 2016-01-5 00:00:00 to 2016-01-22 00:00:00. but currently spark is executing whole data.

Comment: my actual dates are ISO(2016-01-5T18:30:00Z} to ISO(2016-01-22T18:30:00Z).

Comment: So it doesn't when you pass above as `"mongo.input.query"`?

Comment: error is gone but code is scanning whole date instead of selected date range. As shown below lines,                                                                                                Finished task 164.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 164) in 10829 ms on localhost (165/10032). It has created 10032 task instead of 0 since I dont have feb-2016 data.

Comment: For starters `2016-01-5T18:30:00Z` is not a valid ISO-8601 representation.

Comment: I already got your point but question was, if I put date range, spark should not scan whole mongo db. It should only give me data in between that date range. Can converting these into ObjectId () will work?

Comment: To be honest I don't know. It could be an issue with representation (although if driver expects strict JSON it should handle dates as well). Could you check if it works on other types?